# Using Applescript to open MS Powerpoint 2016 file

Tags: applescript, powerpoint

I am trying to automate the conversion of a MS PowerPoint (Version 15.30) 2016 file using AppleScript.  I have the following script:

```
on savePowerPointAsPDF(documentPath, PDFPath)
    tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
        open alias documentPath
        tell active presentation
            delay 1
            save in PDFPath as save as PDF
        end tell
        quit
    end tell
end savePowerPointAsPDF

savePowerPointAsPDF("Macintosh HD:Users:xx:Dropbox:zz yy:file.pptx", "Macintosh HD:Users:xx:Dropbox:zz yy:file.pdf")
```

This script works fine except:

1. The first time I run it, I get the "Grant Access" dialog boxes.
2. All the times I run it, I get a dialog box that says: 
   "The file name has been moved or deleted."

Once I click through all these dialog boxes, it works fine.  I have tried using POSIX file names, but with no success.  I could not get a path with a space in it to work.

The following worked with Excel for solving the first problem, but does not seem to work with PowerPoint:

```
set tFile to (POSIX path of documentPath) as POSIX file
```

In summary, I am just trying to use AppleScript to open a PowerPoint file using PowerPoint 2016 for the Mac.  The path and the filename may contain spaces and other macOS allowed non-alphanumeric characters in them.

Any suggestions on how can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **save** command of **Powerpoint** need an existing file to avoid issues.

To avoid issue with the **open** command, convert the path to an `alias object` (the command must be outside of the '`tell application`' block, like this:

```
on savePowerPointAsPDF(documentPath, PDFPath)
    set f to documentPath as alias -- this line must be outside of the 'tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"' block  to avoid issues with the open command

    tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
        launch
        open f
        -- **  create a file to avoid issues with the saving command **
        set PDFPath to my createEmptyFile(PDFPath) -- the handler return a file object (this line must be inside of the 'tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"' block to avoid issues with the saving command)
        delay 1
        save active presentation in PDFPath as save as PDF
        quit
    end tell
end savePowerPointAsPDF

on createEmptyFile(f)
    do shell script "touch " & quoted form of POSIX path of f -- create file (this command do nothing when the PDF file exists)
    return (POSIX path of f) as POSIX file
end createEmptyFile

savePowerPointAsPDF("Macintosh HD:Users:xx:Dropbox:zz yy:file.pptx", "Macintosh HD:Users:xx:Dropbox:zz yy:file.pdf")
```

Comment: This works great, except, I had to add a "delay 1" between the "do shell" and "return" statements in the createEmptyFile function.  Otherwise, it would sometimes work and sometimes not.  Thanks very much!!

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for sharing.  Do you have any suggestions why "save as JPG" would not work?  I'm not getting any errors, but slide jpgs are never created.