# where is the official documentation AppleScript commands for Powerpoint?

Tags: macos, applescript, powerpoint, automator

I find multiple questions/answers about automating Powerpoint 16 for OSX using AppleScript, such as:
[Using Applescript to open MS Powerpoint 2016 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886380/using-applescript-to-open-ms-powerpoint-2016-file)

Where is the official documentation / API of AppleScript commands for Powerpoint?

Note: Yes, I googled it for a while before asking this.

*Update*
Powerpoint does not appear in Script Editor -> Window -> Library
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have or use Microsoft products and would assume if there was any official documentation, other then an *applications* **AppleScript** *dictionary file*, I'd suspect you have to acquire it from the developer of the *application*.

However, if any give *application* has more than basic support, e.g. `open`, `close`, `quit`, etc., then the *application* should contain an **AppleScript** *dictionary file*, i.e. **appname.sdef** that can be viewed from the **Library** in **Script Editor**.

**Script Editor** > **Window** > **Library**, or: **⇧⌘L**

If it's not already in the **Library** , it can be added by clicking the **(+)** button and navigating to and selecting it in the *dialog sheet* that appears when clicking the button.

Once added to the **Library**, select the target *application* and either *double-click* it or click the icon of the books in the **Toolbar** of the **Library**.

Comment: I've added a screenshot in my question: Powerpoint does not appear in Script Editor -> Window -> Library

Comment: @David Portabella, Did you ne see where I said, "If it's not already in the **Library** , it can be added by clicking the **(+)** button and navigating to and selecting it in the _dialog sheet_ that appears when clicking the button.", or did you already try that?

Comment: hi, I was looking for that .sdef file, but it took a while. I found it here: /Applications/Microsoft PowerPoint.app/Contents/Resources/PowerPoint.sdef
  Thanks!

Comment: @David Portabella, You do not need to find the actual .sdef file, simple select the target app and it will add the app to the Library

Answer (score 1):

No such documentation has been published recently. Microsoft did publish material like this while Office 2008 was on the market, because that version lacked VBA and AppleScript was the only way to automate it. Fortunately, I downloaded copies back then  and have reposted them to my web site: [Office AppleScript Reference - Cool Code](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2020/10/office-applescript-reference-cool-code/)

Comment: Sorry, spelling mistake in the URL. This is correct: http://www.brandwares.com/downloads/Office_AppleScript_Documentation.zip

Answer (score 1):

Once you're in the script editor go to the main menu and open the application library (don't know the exact menu name as im not at the mac right now) and select Microsoft PowerPoint.

If there's really no reference (I doubt that - but as I said I'm not at the mac right now) then check this link, 'its old but dictionaries usually don't change:
http://www.codemunki.com/PPT2004AppleScriptRef.pdf

Comment: The dictionary in this case doesn't get you very far. I've managed to glean a very few examples of useful AppleScript for PowerPoint.

Comment: I've added a screenshot in my question: Powerpoint does not appear in Script Editor -> Window -> Library

Answer (score 1):

“File > Open Dictionary…”, or <kbd>⌘⇧O</kbd>

Select “Microsoft Powerpoint” to view everything it supports (which is quite a lot in Jan 2024).